# Why does outgoing delivered SMS sent correctly now show Red failure to send dot?

Tags: samsung, sms

I'm using Samsung text messages. The problem I'm having is with outgoing text messages that were already sent correctly and received by my recipients. The red dots appeared out of nowhere as of yesterday.

[image]

I'd like to know how to get this resolved without losing my text messages. I'm not sure if this issue applies to Google or Samsung App, either way, it needs resolving. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think they are showing that they have been read or they havent been read after so many hours.  Not sure as I dont use that feature.  Thats what whatsapp is for.

Comment: Welcome to the Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. Does tapping the red dots do something?